# I cant seem to grab a users status

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
const { Discord, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

const user =
    message.mentions.users.first() ||
    message.author || client.users.cache.get((u) => u.id === args[0]);
const avatar = user.displayAvatarURL();
const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
const status = user.presence.status;
const clientStatus = user.presence.clientStatus;

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`This is ${user.username}`)
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setDescription("Users info:")
    .setFooter(`${user.id}`, avatar)
    .setThumbnail(avatar)
    .setTimestamp(Date.now())
    .addFields(
        { name: "User tag", value: `${user.tag}` },
        { name: "nickname", value: `${member.nickname}` || "none" },
        { name: "joined Discord", value: `${user.createdAt}` },
        { name: "joined Server", value: `${member.joinedAt}` },
        { name: "Roles", value: `${member.roles.cache.size - 1}` },
        { name: "status", value: `${status}` },
        { name: "Device", value: `${clientStatus}` }
    );

message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
```

ERROR:

```
const status = user.presence.status;
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you presented in your question, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent enabled. Also note that the presence intent is privileged, so you need to allow it in the Discord Developer Portal.

[image]

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

[`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) has no property `.presence`, use [`GuildMember.presence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=presence) instead.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_PRESENCES"] });

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content == "!status") {
        const status = message.member?.presence?.status;
        if (!status) {
            message.channel.send("Couldn't read your status!");
            return;
        }
        message.channel.send(status);
    }
});
```

[image]

To apply this example to your code, change the following:

```js
// ... member defined ...
const status = member?.presence?.status;
const clientStatus = member?.presence?.clientStatus;
```

<sub>Using discord.js `^13.0.1`.</sub>